How to get textContent of link with tiptap editor?
If I'm using tiptap editor and, I have the cursor in the middle of a link, I can use editor.getAttributes('link') to get the link attributes, but how do I get the text contents of that element?
<a href="/">cursor is here</a>

How do I get the text cursor is here?
I'm trying to build a link UI where you can edit both the content and the href similar to how google docs or wordpress does it.

Considering that getAttributes('link') is DOM element you need, it would be getAttributes('link').textContent. Did you try this? Since you already aware of this property, it's unclear what the problem is

Unfortunately getAttributes('link') is not the dom element, it's an object containing attributes of the link, like {rel: ..., href: ...}, it doesn't contain the textConent :(

Selecting the link text, then waiting, then accessing the selected text through the state or window.getSelection seems to work.
this.editor.chain().focus().extendMarkRange('link').run();

window.setTimeout(() => {
  const { state } = this.editor;
  const { from, to } = state.selection;
  console.log(state.doc.textBetween(from, to, ''));

  // or

  console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
}, 100);

